# XML Searching and Parsing

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have an XML file that I am trying to search using Java.  I just need to find an element by its Tag name and then find that Tag's value.  So for example:

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="https://company.com/test/xslt/processing_report.xslt"?>
<Certificate xmlns="urn:us:net:exchangenetwork:Company">
  <Value1>Veggie</Value1>
  <Value2>Fruits</Value2>
    <type1>Apple</type1>
       <FindME>Red</FindME>
  <Value3>Bread</Value3>
</Certificate>
```

I want to find the value inside of the FindME Tag.  I can't use XPath because different files can have different structures, but they always have a FindME tag. Lastly I am looking for the simplest piece of code, I do not care much about performance.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
    XPathFactory f = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPathExpression expr = f.newXPath().compile(
            "//*[local-name() = 'FindME']/text()");
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("src/test.xml"); //your XML file

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
```

Explained :

`//*` - match any element node - no matter where they are

`local-name()` = 'FindME' - where local name - i.e; not the full path - matches 'FindME'

`text()` - get the node value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read up on XPath because it can very easily solve this problem. So can using getElementsByTagName in the DOM API.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use XPath. All you need to do is use **//FindMe** ([read here on // usage](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)) expression. This finds a the "FindMe" elements from any where in the xml irrespective of its parent or path from the root.

*If you are using namespaces then make sure you are making the parser aware of that*

Comment: Can you show me an example?  I've tried all sorts of parsers.

Comment: oooh.. I think the namespaces might be the problem.  How do I make the parser aware of that?

Comment: `//*[local-name() = 'FindMe']` will not take namespace into consideration

Comment: This expression will fetch all nodes with local names equal to 'FindMe' (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name)

Answer (score 1):

```
String findMeVal = null;

InputStream is = //...
XmlPullParser parser = //...
parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true);
parser.setInput(is, null);

int event;
while (XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT != (event = parser.next())) {
    if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        if ("FindME".equals(parser.getName())) {
            findMeVal = parser.nextText();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```